# My Delphi Program Seems to be Leaking

Tags: delphi, memory, memory-leaks

Ok, so I'm pretty new to Delphi (as you'll see from my code - try not to laugh too hard and hurt yourselves), but I've managed to make a little desktop canvas color picker. It works, kinda, and that's why I'm here :D

It seems to be leaking. It starts off using about 2 MB of memory, and climbs up about 2 kB per second until it reaches about 10 MB after 10 minutes or so. On my dual core 2.7 ghz cpu, it's using anywhere from 5% to 20% cpu power, fluctuating. My computer became unresponsive after running it for about 10 minutes without stopping the timer.

You can see in the source code below that I am freeing the TBitmap (or trying to, not sure if it's doing it, doesn't seem to be working).

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetCursorPos(MousePos);

  try
    Canvas1 := TCanvas.Create;
    Canvas1.Handle := GetDC(0);
    Pxl  := TBitmap.Create;
    Pxl.Width  := 106;
    Pxl.Height := 106;
    W := Pxl.Width;
    H := Pxl.Height;
    T := (W div 2);
    L := (H div 2);
    Zoom := 10;
    Rect1 := Rect(MousePos.X - (W div Zoom), MousePos.Y - (H div Zoom), MousePos.X + (W div Zoom), MousePos.Y + (H div Zoom));
    Rect2 := Rect(0, 0, H, W);
    Pxl.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect2, Canvas1, Rect1);
    Pxl.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
    Pxl.Canvas.MoveTo(T, 0);
    Pxl.Canvas.LineTo(L, H);
    Pxl.Canvas.MoveTo(0, T);
    Pxl.Canvas.LineTo(W, L);
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap := Pxl;
  finally
    Pxl.Free;
  end;

  try
    Pxl2 := TBitmap.Create;
    Pxl2.Width  := 1;
    Pxl2.Height := 1;
    Box1 := MousePos.X;
    Box2 := MousePos.Y;

    BitBlt(Pxl2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 1, 1, GetDC(0), Box1, Box2, SRCCOPY);
    C := Pxl2.Canvas.Pixels[0, 0];
    Coord.Text := IntToStr(Box1) + ', ' + IntToStr(Box2);
    DelColor.Text := ColorToString(C);
    HexColor.Text := IntToHex(GetRValue(C), 2) + IntToHex(GetGValue(C), 2) + IntToHex(GetBValue(C), 2);
    RGB.Text := IntToStr(GetRValue(C)) + ', ' + IntToStr(GetGValue(C)) + ', ' + IntToStr(GetBValue(C));
    Panel1.Color := C;
  finally
    Pxl2.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    if Timer1.Enabled then
      begin
        Timer1.Enabled := false;
        Panel2.Caption := 'Got it! Press Enter to reset.';
      end
    else
      begin
        Timer1.Enabled := true;
        Panel2.Caption := 'Press Enter to lock color.';
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Note: The timer is set to run every 10 ms, if that makes any difference.

ANY and all help figuring out why this is leaking and using so much resources would be greatly appreciated!

You can nab the project here if you want it (Delphi 2010): http://www.mediafire.com/file/cgltcy9c2s80f74/Color%20Picker.rar

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I'll try pulling them out. Are they actually hurting anything, or are they just not needed?

Comment: why use a timer? Shouldn't you use OnMouseMove? No point running timer when idle.

Comment: True, but then it couldn't update the color if you kept the mouse still over an animation or something that might change colors. Is the timer the reason for all the CPU usage, or is the the one constantly using more memory, or both?

Comment: Where do you get these readings? Are you sure you are using the right statistics to draw these conclusions?

Comment: Also you should create objects you want to free before the try...finally. Not in the try finally. Canvas1 and Pxl. And what is Pxl2?

Comment: Hi Lars, the readings, assuming you are meaning memory and cpu usage, are coming from simply observing the application in Windows Task Manager.I'm going to try moving the create objects outside - will it make any difference? What's the downside to having them there, or is it just general best practice?

Comment: Pxl is the 106x106 screenshot seen in the zoomed preview, and Pxl2 is a 1x1 screenshot of just the pixel under the mouse cursor, used to get the color codes that are in the text boxes and also to set the color on the color panel.

Comment: It's probably not ideal to use Pxl and Pxl2, like I said, I'm pretty much a noob to all this, so if it can be done with just the main Pxl (I'm sure it can), I'll take a look and see what I can figure out.

Comment: Edit: you're right, I stopped using Pxl2 after the first revision. I'm now wondering why it's even letting me free something that doesn't even exist.

Comment: @Clowerweb, if you find the answer **yourself** do not edit that in the question, create an answer to your own question, that's the recommend way, otherwise you'll mix up things too much. Also if people upvote the answer to your own question you'll get +10 for each upvote :-).

Comment: This code: `function DesktopColor(const X, Y: Integer): TColor; begin   Color1 := TCanvas.Create;   try     Color1.Handle := DC; Result := GetPixel(Color1.Handle, X, Y);   finally     Color1.Free;   end; end;` has an error, upon the free the DC will be released, not what you want with a cached DC!

Comment: @Johan good tip, except it's making me wait to answer my own question because my rating is under 100. I think I have about an hour left before I can post it, but I will do that and remove the edit from the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @Johan ah you're right, I can probably remove all the "Free" statements from the whole thing, actually. I tried it before to see what would happen and it didn't seem to have any side effects, and FastMM4 wasn't reporting any leaks, so it should be good to go without them.

Comment: @Johan turns out we were both wrong - I removed Color1.Free; and it started leaking again (but only when the mouse moved?), so I guess it stays. For some reason it's part of what is helping keep it leak free.

Comment: HINT: ALWAYS USE DELPHI TOGETHER WITH FASTMM! Every single Delphi user will tell you this!

Comment: @Altar I have FastMM and mentioned it a few times in this discussion - it wasn't reporting any leaks. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution (finally) after tinkering around with it a bit and following a few of the pointers on here. No one really hit it right on the head, but everyone was on the right track. The problem was that I was calling `GetDC()` **inside** the FUNCTION (and in earlier versions the timer procedure as well). Moving it outside of "try ... finally" while keeping it in the function (as suggested) still didn't yield results, but it was getting close and gave me the idea that actually worked. So I moved it a bit further away - into the Form's `OnCreate` event.

Here's the final code:

```
function DesktopColor(const X, Y: Integer): TColor;
begin
  Color1 := TCanvas.Create;
  Color1.Handle := DC;
  Result := GetPixel(Color1.Handle, X, Y);
  Color1.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  GetCursorPos(Pos);
  Rect1 := Rect(Pos.X - (W div Zoom), Pos.Y - (H div Zoom), Pos.X + (W div Zoom), Pos.Y + (H div Zoom));
  Rect2 := Rect(0, 0, H, W);
  Pxl.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect2, Canvas1, Rect1);
  Pxl.Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Pxl.Canvas.MoveTo(T, 0);
  Pxl.Canvas.LineTo(L, H);
  Pxl.Canvas.MoveTo(0, T);
  Pxl.Canvas.LineTo(W, L);
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap := Pxl;
  Coord.Text := IntToStr(Pos.X) + ', ' + IntToStr(Pos.Y);
  C := DesktopColor(Pos.X, Pos.Y);
  DelColor.Text := ColorToString(C);
  HexColor.Text := IntToHex(GetRValue(C), 2) + IntToHex(GetGValue(C), 2) + IntToHex(GetBValue(C), 2);
  RGB.Text := IntToStr(GetRValue(C)) + ', ' + IntToStr(GetGValue(C)) + ', ' + IntToStr(GetBValue(C));
  Panel1.Color := C;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Pxl := TBitmap.Create;
  Canvas1 := TCanvas.Create;
  DC := GetDC(0);
  Pxl.Width  := 106;
  Pxl.Height := 106;
  Canvas1.Handle := DC;
  W := Pxl.Width;
  H := Pxl.Height;
  T := (W div 2);
  L := (H div 2);
  Zoom := 10;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    if Timer1.Enabled then
      begin
        Timer1.Enabled := false;
        Panel2.Caption := 'Got it! Press Enter to reset.';
      end
    else
      begin
        Timer1.Enabled := true;
        Panel2.Caption := 'Press Enter to lock color.';
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.OnDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ReleaseDC(0, Canvas1.Handle);
  ReleaseDC(0, Color1.Handle);
end;
```

And the final tally: ***drumroll*** CPU usage: 00% idle, 01% spikes if you move the mouse fast enough; Memory usage: ~3,500 kB **solid,** remaining unchanged. I even bumped the timer up from 10 ms to 5 ms and still get the same numbers.

Here's the final project with all the aforementioned fixes: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ebc8b4hzre7q6r5/Color%20Picker.rar

Thanks to everyone who helped, I greatly do appreciate it! I'm going to go ahead and open source the project for everyone who stumbles across this post and finds it useful. No license, do with it whatever you will. No credit necessary, but if you want to leave my name in there, that would be cool :D

Answer (score 5):

You never free your Canvas1 object, leaking both process heap and GDI obj. handles.

Comment: Thanks! At first glance, that seemed to cut the CPU usage in about half, but the memory usage still keeps increasing for some reason.

Comment: This looks like the right answer.  Also, it's worth noting that you can get Delphi to tell you what and where it's leaking.  The "what" is easy. Just set `ReportMemoryLeaksAtShutdown := true`.  The "where" is a bit trickier. For that you need to download the full version of FastMM4 from SourceForge and use FullDebugMode to get stack traces of your memory leaks.  It's got instructions on how to do that with the project.

Comment: Thanks Mason, I actually tried FastMM and even though I had it as the very first "uses" as it instructs, it was still saying that the memory was already allocated, which I thought strange. Could it be my Delphi version?

Comment: @Clowerweb: Was this the first **uses** of your form, or the first **uses** of the DPR?  It has to go in the first **uses** of the DPR for that to work, not just the form.

Comment: Ah thank you, Mason! A friend pointed out that I may be misusing the term "memory leak" in this case. He said it's not a memory leak, it just continues using more memory, where memory leaks are generally defined as the application not freeing the memory it was using after it closes. Not sure if that's correct or not, but it makes sense. Whatever my program is doing, it's using about 2 kB more memory per second WHILE RUNNING (not sure what happens after it's closed).

Comment: @Clowerweb, term is correct, leak is resource taken and not released. Doing so in the loop brings up a leaking pipe analogy. In Win32 it almost impossible to hold something after process ends.

Comment: Ok, so I got FastMM with FullDebugMode running, aaaaaand..... no memory leaks reported? It's interesting because I can watch in task manager as it keeps using more and more memory... so if that isn't a memory leak, what else could be causing that to happen?

Answer (score 2):

As user said above, TCanvas instance which owns DC of desktop window never freed, not releasing DC. I found another DC leak here:

```
BitBlt(Pxl2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, 1, 1, GetDC(0), Box1, Box2, SRCCOPY);
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

This not solves memory leak but explains why Windows becomes unresponsive after 20 minutes (assuming previous issue has been patched already)

---

Every [`GetDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871%28VS.85%29.aspx) call **requires** [`ReleaseDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162920%28VS.85%29.aspx) counter-part. GDI objects in the fact are even more precious than memory.

Comment: Yeah the previous leak was patched but it didn't make that much of a difference. Memory usage still climbs fast, cpu usage starts off between 2% and 10% for about the first 2 minutes, then starts going up to 15% - 20% for the next 7 minutes or so until the pc becomes unresponsive again.

Comment: So what do you suggest for clearing that? It's a function, so it can't really be cleared. Sorry if I sound like a noob, but, I am lol.

Comment: @Clowerweb, expanded on that.

Comment: Thanks man! Cut the CPU usage down to between 2 and 5%, which is about 1/4 where we started at. Still climbing on the memory usage unfortunately, but that's one issue down!

Comment: ReleaseDC is not required for class or private DCs. (But the screen DC is a common DC, not a class or private one.) DCs are exactly as precious as memory.

Comment: Well it looks like I was wrong again. While it seems to be improving, CPU usage does start to creep back up to the ~20% range again after 5 or so minutes, but I wasn't noticing the same performance hit this time. I'd still rather it stay at very low CPU usage.

Comment: @Clowerweb, glad to help. Unfortunately i dont see anything else in your code. @Rob Kennedy, agree about class and private contexts remark, but do not for GDI vs. memory. Memory is much cheaper and GDI leaks are much more destructive.

Comment: I'd upvote you if I could, but not enough rep yet. Getting there :)

Comment: However, it is good to see my answer not downvoted with "interesting" rationale like "not a good answer" or "you said yourself - not solves" :-D

Comment: Started noticing a performance hit on the PC again after about 8 minutes. Not sure what the hell is going on... :(

Comment: @David Heffernan, please don't criticize others' critics toward downvoting and "noise" comments when your history on that topic contains more than hundred entries[.](http://encyclopediadramatica.ch/NO_U)

Comment: @David Heffernan, so you did something which need to be avenged? OK, on file. Just for the record - you are following me, not vice versa. I'd suggest you to stop...

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your code in `DesktopColor`

If the creation or GetDC fails, no resource will be locked and the unlock or free will generate an error, because you are trying to free a resource that does not exist.

The rule is that initialization should always be done before the `try`, because otherwise you will not know whether is is safe to deconstruct the entry.
In this case it's not a huge issue because GetxDC/ReleaseDC does not generate exceptions, it just gives back a 0 if unsuccesful.

Secondly I recommend putting in tests to make sure that your calls using DC's are succesful. When using Delphi objects you don't need that because the exceptions will take care of that, but Windows DC do not use exceptions, so you'll have to do your own testing.  I recommend using assertions, because you can enable then in debug time and disable them when the program is debugged.

But because GetxDC never generates exceptions and to be consistent I'd recommend changing the code into:

```
{$C+} //enable assertions for debug purposes.
//or {$C-} //Disable assertions in production code

function DesktopColor(const X, Y: Integer): TColor;
var 
  Color: TCanvas; 
  Handle: THandle;   
begin     
  Color := TCanvas.Create;
  //If the create fails GetWindowsDC will not get stored anywhere 
  //and we cannot free it. 
  Handle:= GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow); 
  try
    Assert(Handle <> 0);
    Color.Handle := Handle; //Will generate an exception if create failed. 
    Handle := 0;       
    Result := GetPixel(Color.Handle, X, Y);   
  finally   
    //Free the handle if it wasn't transfered to the canvas.
    if Handle <> 0 then ReleaseDC(0, Handle); 
    Color.Free;  //TCanvas.Destroy will call releaseDC on Color.handle.
                 //If the transfer was succesful 
  end; {tryf}   
end;
```

The same arguments apply to `Timer1Timer`.

**Warning**
When you disable assertions Delphi will remove the entire `assert` statement from your project, so don't put any code with side effects into an assert!

**Links:**
Assertions: http://beensoft.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-assert.html

Comment: Thanks! I actually found the solution, but it's making me wait 2 hours to post the answer. It was actually that I had to move it out of the function altogether (moving just outside try...finally didn't work). I moved the GetDC calls to the form's OnCreate event and that did it!

Comment: @Clowerweb, good idea to cache those DC's. I recommend having a look at the sourcecode for `TCanvas`, if you handle your handles like TCanvas handles them then you know you've got the correct handle on those handles.

Comment: Thank you Johan, lots of useful tips. I ended up editing the OP if you want to see the results. I'm just glad that problem is out of the way, it plagued me for a long time, and the answer was so simple.

Comment: BTW, you can employ `Win32Check` instead of `Assert` to have more specific error message.